# Why does C# print out in big endian when I'm on a LE architecture?

Tags: c#, binary, hex, endianness

So I'm currently looking into endianness and I noticed that we read and write binary as well as hex from right to left. Why is that? It goes against every fiber in my body since I'm so used to writing numbers left to right with the normal decimal system.

For instance `01 5E` is `350`. Is it 350 big endian or little endian?

This `Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);` prints out `True` meaning that my current CPU architecture uses Little Endian to read numbers.

Doing this

```
int x = 350;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("X"));
```

Prints out `15E` and this is where I get confused because looking over at https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ at the bottom left corner after inputting `015E` it says that it's 350 Big Endian, so why is it printing out `15E` in my application if my CPU uses Little Endian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness is not usually directly observable - it is an implementation detail right until you do things like blitting between primitive types and raw memory. Your use of `ToString("X")` does not do this - it uses integer rules, and integer rules *hide endianness details*, and use human-friendly rules, i.e. big-endian. So basically: this is a non-issue in your case. If you were using `unsafe`, `BitConverter`, or similar: then it might matter.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, 350 is stored as 5E 01 00 00, but you're printing the int number expressed in hex, which is a human readable operation, which prints 15E. If you cast the int to a byte array, or saved the int to disk, and dumped the bytes as hex, you'd see the 5E 01 00 00. Endianness is really an intimate internal CPU architecture thing.

Comment: Right, but how does my CPU read `5E 01 00 00` as 350? My CPU uses Little Endian meaning that it would read the least significant byte first which is the one all the way to the right, in this case `00` which would be 16^0 and then 16^1, then continue this.. 00 which is now 16^2.. 16^3. Then it would get to 01 so 16^4 which is `65536` and now we're way over 350.

Comment: @Riley it doesn't; that's not what you're seeing: `ToString("X")` isn't doing anything related to endianness; it is doing math like `val & 0xFF` and `val >>= 8` (if you see what I mean), and this kind of math gives the same result *regardless of endianness*

Comment: Oh, that would explain why I'm so confused!

Comment: (or to be clear, `ToString` *could* use unsafe code to look at the bytes directly, but it is **required** to give the same output on any architecture, so if it does that: it must internally take endianness into account and compensate by reversing the order itself)

Comment: So how is the value `350` stored in RAM for the CPU to read? is it `5E 01 00 00` which in binary would be `1010 1110 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000` and that's not right if the CPU tries to read the least significant byte first.